# NodeJS, socket.io, Yandex API Geo не открывается карта

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, socket.io, яндекс-карта-api

Не открывается карта, ошибок вроде бы нет....

```js
<script>
    const socket = io()
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Подключение установлено!')
    })
    // получаем данные от сервера
    socket.on('hello', (counter) => {
      console.log(counter)
    })
     socket.on('aver', (aver) => {
      console.log(aver)
    })

     socket.on('yandex', (yandex) => {
      console.log(yandex)
    })
         socket.on('mylnikov', (mylnikov) => {
      console.log(mylnikov)
    })
    
    socket.on('opencellid', (opencellid) => {
      console.log(opencellid)
    })
    
    // отправляем данные на сервер
    socket.emit('hi', {
      counter: 'test'
    })

    
    function init() {
     socket.on('average', (average) => {
    //socket.on('yandex', (yandex) => {
     //socket.on('mylnikov', (mylnikov) => {
     // socket.on('opencellid', (opencellid) => {
      
    const myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [57.73065948486328, 34.17068862915039],
            zoom: 15,
            behaviors: ['default', 'scrollZoom']
        }),
        // Создаем коллекцию.
        myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(),
        // Создаем массив с данными.
        myPoints = [
            { coords: [57.73065948486328, 34.17068862915039], text: 'Трактир' },
            { coords: [55.78972919255, 37.35810886834], text: 'Кафе' }
        ];

    // Заполняем коллекцию данными.
    for (var i = 0, l = myPoints.length; i < l; i++) {
        var point = myPoints[i];
        myCollection.add(new ymaps.Placemark(
            point.coords, {
                balloonContentBody: point.text
            }
        ));
    }

    // Добавляем коллекцию меток на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);

    // Создаем экземпляр класса ymaps.control.SearchControl
    var mySearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
            // Заменяем стандартный провайдер данных (геокодер) нашим собственным.
            provider: new CustomSearchProvider(myPoints),
            // Не будем показывать еще одну метку при выборе результата поиска,
            // т.к. метки коллекции myCollection уже добавлены на карту.
            noPlacemark: true,
            resultsPerPage: 5
        });

    // Добавляем контрол в верхний правый угол,
    myMap.controls
        .add(mySearchControl, { right: 10, top: 10 })
        .add('smallZoomControl');
        
        })
//})
//})
//})
        
}


// Провайдер данных для элемента управления ymaps.control.SearchControl.
// Осуществляет поиск геообъектов в по массиву points.
// Реализует интерфейс IGeocodeProvider.
function CustomSearchProvider(points) {
    this.points = points;
}

// Провайдер ищет по полю text стандартным методом String.ptototype.indexOf.
CustomSearchProvider.prototype.geocode = function (request, options) {
    var promise = new ymaps.util.Promise(),
        geoObjects = new ymaps.GeoObjectArray(),
        // Сколько результатов нужно пропустить.
        offset = options.skip || 0,
        // Количество возвращаемых результатов.
        limit = options.results || 20;

    var points = [];
    // Ищем в свойстве text каждого элемента массива.
    for (var i = 0, l = this.points.length; i < l; i++) {
        var point = this.points[i];
        if (point.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            points.push(point);
        }
    }
    // При формировании ответа можно учитывать offset и limit.
    points = points.splice(offset, limit);
    // Добавляем точки в результирующую коллекцию.
    for (var i = 0, l = points.length; i < l; i++) {
        var point = points[i],
            coords = point.coords,
                    text = point.text;

        geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
            name: text + ' name',
            description: text + ' description',
            balloonContentBody: '<p>' + text + '</p>',
            boundedBy: [coords, coords]
        }));
    }

    promise.resolve({
        // Геообъекты поисковой выдачи.
        
        geoObjects: geoObjects,
        // Метаинформация ответа.
        metaData: {
            geocoder: {
                // Строка обработанного запроса.
                request: request,
                // Количество найденных результатов.
                found: geoObjects.getLength(),
                // Количество возвращенных результатов.
                results: limit,
                // Количество пропущенных результатов.
                skip: offset
            }
        }

    });

    // Возвращаем объект-обещание.
    return promise;
};

 ymaps.ready(init)
  </script>
```